# Hungerian Algorithm ( Assignment Model )

Tags: hungarian-algorithm

```
          Duty 1   Duty 2   Duty 3   Duty 4
Staff 1   $50      $50       -       $20
Staff 2   $70      $40      $20      $30
Staff 3   $90      $30      $50       -
Staff 4   $70      $70      $60      $20
```

**Note that Staff 1 cannot do Duty 3 and Staff 3 cannot do Duty 4.**

Any ideas how to find values that are (-), or how to solve this problem using the Hungarian algorithm?

Comment: Use a really large value like 9999 for the blanks and you're basically guaranteed that they won't be chosen.